# How to control azure storage account costs in Azure when using WAD tables

Tags: azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-diagnostics

We do not use our Azure storage account for anything except standard Azure infrastructure concerns (i.e. no application data). For example, the only tables we have are the WAD (Windows Azure Diagnostics) ones, and our only blob containers are for vsdeploy, iislogfiles, etc. We do not use queues in the app either.

14 cents per gigabyte isn't breaking the bank yet, but after several months of logging WAD info to these tables, the storage account is quickly nearing 100 GB.

We've found that deleting rows from these tables is painful, with continuation tokens, etc, because some contain millions of rows (have been logging diagnostics info since June 2011).

One idea I have is to "cycle" storage accounts. Since they contain diagnostic data used by MS to help us debug unexpected exceptions and errors, we could log the WAD info to storage account A for a month, then switch to account B for the following month, then C.

By the time we get to the 3rd month, it's a pretty safe bet that we no longer need the diagnostics data from storage account A, and can safely delete it, or delete the tables themselves rather than individual rows.

Has anyone tried an approach like this? How do you keep WAD storage costs under control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Account rotation would work, if you don't mind the manual work to be done updating your configurations and redeploying every month. That would probably be the most cost-effective route, as you wouldn't have to pay for all the transaction to query and delete the logs.

There are some tools that will purge logs for you. Azure Diagnostics Manager from Cerebrata [which is currently showing me an ad to the right :) ] will do it, though it's a manual process too. I think they have some Powershell commandlets to do it as well.

Comment: Yes they showed the ad to me as well as soon as I posted the question. We are a non-profit, so budget is of concern when it comes to 3rd party tools. Changing the diagnostics string isn't of concern, we change it anyway because our csdef and cscfg are in public source control (open source project) -- so we remove it before checking it in anyway.

Comment: I actually use the Cerebrata stuff anyway - it's pretty handy for keeping an eye on your apps. But if you don't use diagnostics or trace logging, then it's probably not worth the money just for the log purging features.